# Safari browser doesn't send referer

Tags: ios, browser, safari, referer

I want to redirect url, general code is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="referrer" content="always">
    <script>
        document.location.replace(url);
    </script>
</head>
```

Other browsers can send referer, why the Safari is not?

How to send referer in the Safari browser on the ios?

Can you help me please.

Answer (score 1):

The transition to many websites to https websites instead of http websites has caused a loss of referrer tags; this occurs because when transferring from an http link into a https link, the referrer information is dropped.

So if you're on an http page, and link off to an https page, no referrer header is available when you land there.

One solution to this is to change your pages to https; then your visitors will be going from https to https, and the referrer information will come along as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add this to your

This should fix it for desktop Safari. It may not fix it for ios safari. You may want to use content of origin or place it as a hidden field in the page via JavaScript.

A good explanation: http://smerity.com/articles/2013/where_did_all_the_http_referrers_go.html

Comment: Thank you, I also use <meta name="referrer" content="always"> in my code, but does not work. Finally, I use PHP to solve the problem.

Comment: @Aland How did you solve this problem using php?
I am facing an issue - my website is not working when using safari in private mode.
I think http_reffer is not getting there? Have any idea?

Comment: Just place javascript to do the redirect.

Comment: $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://your.referer.com/');
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);@Vikas Chauhan

Answer (score 0):

I You using frame(in my case) then use `document.location.href = url;` instead of `replace(url)`